# Does "enhance their position" sound natural in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

I'm writing an essay about group polarization. My question is..

In group polarization, when individuals in a group have a discussion on a topic, they are presented with new reasons that **enhance their position.**

If I use "enhance their position" in the sentence, could it mean "accentuate their existing attitude or support their position about the topic"?

Comment: When you say 'accentuate their existing attitude...', are you attempting to convey something mostly-positive, as in "their position becomes more well-considered and thoughtful" or something mostly-negative, as in "their position becomes rigid and harder to debate"?

Comment: To me, ***enhance*** carries overtones of approval - not really present in ***bolster.***

Comment: Oh, I meant the negative thing like "reinforce their opinions on a topic"? Let's say I'm against gun control, and after a group discussion, my position about the topic is reinforced to the point where I end up more opposed to it than I was originally. –

Comment: For *negative* overtones, you'd talk about ***hardening** their position*.